# node.js/javascript - how to map a variable in a relative path

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a `setFilelocation` and I'm using this variable in multiple `.js` files. So the same path is set every time I use this variable.

Is there any way I can use this variable as a global variable and I can hardcode this location only once, such as:

```
var setFileLocation = '/home/name/parent1/parentdirec/direc/qa.json';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using node you can use `require`

I do this with config info like this

in one file called `config.js` for example

```
module.exports = {
    v1: somevalue,
    fileLocation: "/default/file/loc",
    computePath: (dir, subdir, file) {
         //use Vasans example here
    }
 };
```

Then in your code require config.js

```
var config = require('./config.js');
```

And you will have access to the variable or the funtion to create the path, whichever way you want

Answer (score 0):

Have a global function instead which will take these inputs and return the full path.

```
var path = require('path')
function computePath(dir, subdir, file) {
    var pathParts = [];
    pathParts.push(dir, subdir, file);    
    return pathParts.join(path.sep);
}
```

Comment: if within the subdirectory there are more file that i want to access, how can i do with this??

Comment: You can call it with different values for the 3rd parameter, if that's what you;re looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Set it as a global variable:

`global.setFileLocation = '/home/name/parent1/parentdirec/direc/qa.json';`

Then you can use it in any place of your code:
`console.log(setFileLocation);`

But remember that using global variable like that is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

there are many options

1. using global (not suggest because in the practise, node.js app should not contain global variable)

   global.setFileLocation = '/home/name/parent1/parentdirec/direc/qa.json';
2. export to utility module and import it

   ==== YOUR_APP/config.js ====
   module.exports = {
       fileLocation: "/home/name/parent1/parentdirec/direc/qa.json"
    };

   === YOUR_APP/SOME_PATH/a.js ====
   require('rootpath')();

   var config = require('/config')
   // config.fileLocation